$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$. Is $n^{4} \cdot f(n)$ injective?
$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order n. Domain: Nonnegative integers.
Is $n^{4} \cdot f(n)$ an injective function?
I don't know the answer.
My current progress:
There is 49866 results of $f(n)$ here.
I made a list with 49866 values of $n^{4} \cdot f(n)$. All elements are distincts.
Possible strategies:

Prove $n^{b} \cdot f(n)$ is not injective for all positive integer $b$.
Use formulas for $n$ with few primes in its integer factoring.
Use lower and upper bounds of $f(n)$
Use $a^{4} \cdot f(a) = b^{4} \cdot f(b)$ and $a < b$ implies $f(a) > f(b)$.

Relevant information:
$n \cdot f(n)$, $n^{2} \cdot f(n)$ and $n^{3} \cdot f(n)$ are not injective.
Why the question is interesting or important:
I think this question is relevant to me because I want to learn more about $f(n)$. I'm wondering if is there some $n^{b} \cdot f(n)$ that is injective. I think this is relevant to our community because we don't know a general formula for $f(n)$.

Can you add the numbers for $nf(n)$, $n^2f(n)$ and $n^3f(n)$ (where the injectivity fails)?

@Peter, Thank you. You help me a lot. :)

$$18 \cdot f(18) = 45 \cdot f(45) = 90$$ $$930^{2} \cdot f(930) = 1395^{2} \cdot f(1395) = 15568200$$ $$35464^{3} \cdot f(35464) = 44330^{3} \cdot f(44330) = 5575363247168000$$
